# iOS firebase Mach-O Linker Error without cocapods

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, firebase

I'm trying to import Firebase into my iOS app. I followed this tutorial for doing this manually with Objective-C (as opposed to using CocoaPods).

http://www.mokacoding.com/blog/setting-up-firebase-without-cocoapods/

When I try to build my project, I get the following errors:

```
"Apple Mach-O Linker Error"
"Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"
```

I'm familiar with the Linux CLI (less so with Macs), but I don't understand how to apply the `-v` flag to XCode's build process to get more info.

I've been Googling this for the last 3 hours, but every answer I find seems to be directed at users who weren't using an XCode workspace with CocoaPods.

I don't have CocoaPods installed, so I don't think this is my issue. Despite that I have converted my project and properly imported it into an XCode workspace, this still didn't solve my problem.

My app is a Swift project, and I have imported the `modulemap`, `firebase.h`, and `googleServices.plist` files.

I've also made my Header and Library search paths recursive for the entire project folder in an attempt to fix this.

Here's my project navigation. Although at this point I suspect it's some kind of build setting that isn't correct.

[image]

Some selected answers I've tried to apply without success:

- [Apple Mach -O Linker command failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33536032/apple-mach-o-linker-command-failed/40969381)
- [In Xcode how do I create a new workspace and add 1 project to it so that I can see the project and its files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38298219/in-xcode-how-do-i-create-a-new-workspace-and-add-1-project-to-it-so-that-i-can-s)
- [Framework not found GoogleToolboxForMac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40358719/framework-not-found-googletoolboxformac)
- [Adding system header search path to Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428216/adding-system-header-search-path-to-xcode)
- https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/258
- [Apple Mach-O Linker & Ditto Error - Xcode 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39545880/apple-mach-o-linker-ditto-error-xcode-8)
- https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/198
- https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ios-xcode-8-apple-mach-o-linker-ld-error-group-in-xcode/89903

Comment: You should be able to see more info about the failure in the Xcode build log - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19014359/how-do-i-view-the-full-build-log-on-xcode5. Perhaps missing -ObjC in OTHER_LDFLAGS?

Comment: I have -ObjC in OTHER_LDFLAGS

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to xcode 9.2 fixes this. It appears to be an issue with earlier versions not properly handling linking.

Which is misleading b/c the firebase documentation indicates it's compatible with xcode 8. But I think that's assuming you use cocoapods. If you don't, and instead try to link the obj-c frameworks you need xcode 9+

Once I knew how to examine the more verbose linking error, googling for x86_64 led me to some helpful answers.

This and other answers helped me investigate upgrading.

[ld: framework not found Stripe for architecture x86_64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34798741/ld-framework-not-found-stripe-for-architecture-x86-64/38298354#38298354)